# How to remove selection from a listbox in html by javascript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After I click an item on a listbox, I'll do this processing then I need to remove this selection as it was at the first time so that I can click the same item again and fire the event of selected index change.

Comment: do you need any more help with this question? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the [`selectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534624(v=vs.85).aspx) property to -1:

```
// Plain JS:
document.getElementById("myList").selectedIndex = -1;

// Using jQuery to select the element:
$("#myList")[0].selectedIndex = -1;
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n84AW/**